# using correct parameters/flags for mount() syscall

Tags: linux-kernel, mount, system-calls, strace

I  am trying to understand how `mount()` syscall works and what flags it is using. My filesystem is ext4 and I am remounting it to read-only. I am using mount command in Debian and starting it with `strace`.

In the output of `strace`, I can see the actual syscall:

```
mount("/dev/root", "/", 0x3a74500, MS_MGC_VAL|MS_RDONLY|MS_REMOUNT, NULL) = 0
```

According to `man 2 mount`, the parameters for mount() syscall are:

```
int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
      const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
      const void *data);
```

I don't understand the third parameter (`0x3a74500`), which should be filesystem type. I have expected, I should use "ext4".

What does this hex string `0x3a74500` mean ?

Comment: This can be a pointer to the char* definition, but it should have shown you the text for my best understanding. Do you always see the same address? Can you try different filesystem types and see if this changes?

Comment: Ishay Peled - you are right, the value is different each time.